# How to use heatmap written in javascript in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm having a js file that draw heatmap based on the points given .I want the same work to be done with reactjs  .How can i do this ?

heatmap.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Heatmap Test Code</title>
<script src='http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/assets/js/heatmap.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='heatMap' style="height: 742px">
    <canvas width="1024" height="742" style="position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
<script> 
  var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
    container: document.getElementById('heatMap')
  });

  var testData = {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        data: [{'x': 948, 'y': 71, 'value': 1}, {'x': 949, 'y': 70, 'value': 1}, {'x': 948, 'y': 69, 'value': 1}, {'x': 946, 'y': 67, 'value': 1},  {'x': 390, 'y': 39, 'value': 1}, {'x': 376, 'y': 39, 'value': 1}, {'x': 288, 'y': 16, 'value': 1}, {'x': 200, 'y': 12, 'value': 1}, {'x': 134, 'y': 12, 'value': 1}, {'x': 96, 'y': 12, 'value': 1}, {'x': 80, 'y': 12, 'value': 1}, {'x': 69, 'y': 15, 'value': 1}, {'x': 65, 'y': 17, 'value': 1}]

  };
  heatmapInstance.setData(testData);  
</script>
</html>
```

I tried the following in reactjs :

In index.html :

```
included the script in index.html (<script src="heatmap.min.js" ></script>)
```

In heat.js :

```
export function heat(){ 
 //code to draw heatmap 
}
```

In app.js :

```
import {heat} from './heat';
class App extends Component {

 componentWillMount(){
  heat();
 }
```

When i run the code in reactjs ,it throws h337 is not defined error .What was the mistake i have done  ?

Comment: you added absolute URL in heatmap.html and relative in index.html.

Comment: @SwaroopDeval , yes I did because I downloaded the heatmap.js file and put it in my local.

Comment: Try including heaptmap via npm: `npm install heatmap.js`

Comment: @Nuhman ,installed heatmap.js and how and where to include  it ?

Comment: Please do below things:
1. can you confirm if your browser successfully downloaded heatmap.min.js, you can check that in network tab of developer tools.
2. Put heat() in componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount
3. Confirm if <script src="heatmap.min.js" ></script> is above the react code (app.js) you added in index.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After `npm install heatmap.js` you can create a basic working heatmap using the following code:

`App.js`

```js
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import h337 from "heatmap.js";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
      // only container is required, the rest will be defaults
      container: document.querySelector('.App')
    });
    // now generate some random data
    var points = [];
    var max = 0;
    var width = 840;
    var height = 400;
    var len = 200;

    while (len--) {
     var val = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
     max = Math.max(max, val);
     var point = {
      x: Math.floor(Math.random()*width),
      y: Math.floor(Math.random()*height),
      value: val
     };
     points.push(point);
   }
   // heatmap data format
  var data = {
    max: max,
    data: points
  };
  // if you have a set of datapoints always use setData instead of addData
  // for data initialization
  heatmapInstance.setData(data);
 })



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-thompson-dxfss)

Comment: How do you plot this as a Leaflet overlay?

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer. @Nuhnam 
Is there have any way to add animation like example in  [heatmap.js](https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-heatmap-animation.html) when using React?

Hope you can help  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is perfect except in my case it gave the following error: `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'data' of object '#<ImageData>'`.

To solve this just go to your `package.json`, then inside `dependencies` replace `"heatmap.js": "^2.0.5"` with `"heatmap.js": "https://github.com/ionata/heatmap.js.git"`.

Reinstall everything by doing `yarn` or `npm install` again and the code should work as expected. In case you don't know which code i'm talking about, it's this:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import h337 from "heatmap.js";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
      // only container is required, the rest will be defaults
      container: document.querySelector('.App')
    });
    // now generate some random data
    var points = [];
    var max = 0;
    var width = 840;
    var height = 400;
    var len = 200;

    while (len--) {
     var val = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
     max = Math.max(max, val);
     var point = {
      x: Math.floor(Math.random()*width),
      y: Math.floor(Math.random()*height),
      value: val
     };
     points.push(point);
   }
   // heatmap data format
  var data = {
    max: max,
    data: points
  };
  // if you have a set of datapoints always use setData instead of addData
  // for data initialization
  heatmapInstance.setData(data);
 })



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```